# How to export image collection data with different projection from Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, modis-reprojection-tool

I am exporting data from Google Earth Engine using `Python` for a specific `region` in a given temporal window.
This what I am doing:

```
from geetools import batch
data = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A1').filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-06-01', '2019-08-01'))\
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
tasks = batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive(data, 'JunJuly2019', region=geometry, scale=1000)
```

This allowsme to save `.tiff` images in my `Google Drive` in a sinusoidal projection. However I would like to change projection. For instance I would like to implement something like this before exporting.

```
myData.reproject('EPSG:4326')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the projection in the export function or in the input file before exporting it. For more info on this with examples take a look at the documentation section in GEE and this website:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections